# How to split a variable into two different variables?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, split, branch

For a game that asks input from the user, I am using an if check to determine what the user said. It's for a text based game here, so when a user inputs "examine table" I want examine to become a variable and table to become another variable so I can evaluate them separately in my script.

A variable named "move" is used for the input.

```
move = input("> ")
```

I want that variable to split into "action" and "object" variables by splitting the two words in half.

How would I go around doing this?

Comment: Usually you post what you've tried first...

Comment: Can you give it a bit of context? What is the variable looks like? A list, a dictionary?

Comment: My knowledge with Python is not sufficient enough to attempt something. I tried to get an example or ideas on how to do this so I could study them.

Comment: `str.split` is what you are looking for ... but I would probably go read up on python basics ... this is pretty basic

Comment: Very basic stuff. Covered in many Python tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to split a string into 2 different variables?

If so,

```
string = 'examine table'
splitString = string.split()
```

giving you the list

```
['examine','table']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
verb, _, params = move.partition(" ")
```

- `verb` will be first word
- `_` will be the separator, whitespace in this case
- `params` will be the rest after the verb

Answer (score 2):

First you want to get the input:

```
varName = raw_input("Enter anything:  ")
```

Then you want to split the input

```
splitted_results = varName.split()
print splitted_results
```

This will give you a list of strings split by empty space.  You can loop through as so:

```
for sr in splitted_results:
    print sr
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a string? If so, split up the string by whatever character you want to with

```
string.split("[character to split by here]")
```

Then, you will get an array. If you only wanted to split by the first character (let's say for example a period):

```
arr = string.split(".")
arr = [arr[0], ','.join(arr[1:])]
```